# How to organise dataFrame like this, in Python:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file which has some information:

1.Movie ID (the first character before a ":")

2.User ID

4.User Rating

3.Date

All elements are splited by a "," but Movie ID, which is separated by a colon

if I create a dataframe like this:

```
 df=pd.read_csv('combined_data_1.txt',header = None,names['Movie_ID','User_ID','Rating','Date'])
```

and print the dataframe, I will get this:

[image]

Which is not correct, obviosly.

So, if you look at the "Movie_ID" column, in the first row, there is a 1:1488844. Only the number "1" (just before the colon) should be in the "Movie_ID" column, not "1:1488844". The rest (1488844) should be in the User_ID column.

Another problem is that not every "Movie_ID" column have its correctly ID, and in this case, it should be "1" until I find another movie id, that again, will be the first number before a colon.

I know that the ids of all the movies follow a sequence, that is: 1,2,3,4,...

Another problem that I saw, was that when I read the file, for some reason a split occours when there is a colon, so after the first row (which doesn't get splited), when a colon appears, a row in "Movie_ID" is created containing only, for example: "2:", not something like the first row.

In the end, I would like to get something like this:

[image]

But I don't know how to organise like this. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: how did you get movie id = 2, 3 ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue might be coming from how your data is being stored and thus parsed due to the way your Movie ID is stored separated by a : (colon) rather than a , (comma) as would be needed in a CSV.

If you are able to parse to have it delineate by commas exclusively. the text before it is opened as a CSV, you may be able to eliminate this issue. I only note this because Pandas does not permit multiple delimiters.

Here is what I was able to come up with regarding making something which delineates by colon and comma for how you desire. While I know this isn't your ultimate goal, hopefully this is able to get you on the right path.

```
import pandas as pd
with open("combined_data_1.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()


#Splitting the data into a list delineated by colons
data = []
for line in lines:
    if(":" in line):
        data.append([])
    else: #Using else here prevents the line containing the colon from being saved.
        data[len(data)-1].append(line)


for x in range(len(data)):
    print("Section " + str(x+1) + ":\n")
    print(str(data[x]) + "\n\n")
```

Comment: What I tried to do was use split `df['Movie_ID'] = df['Movie_ID'].str.split(':')`, but that did not work becuase when the dataFrame was created, when a colon appeared, there was a split, so there were some rows with "1: or 2: , 3:..". To create a dataframe, I used:                     `df=pd.read_csv('combined_data_1.txt',header=None,names['Movie_ID','User_ID','Rating','Date'])` I don't know if there is any parameter that I should use that does't do that automatic split when it finds a colon. I also know that by default, the parameter split, splits when it finds a comma

Comment: I updated my answer with code that converts the file into a 2d list containing what you want in a CSV format. If I understand your intentions correctly, this should make converting to a CSV easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use `shift` with `axis=1` and simply modify the columns:

```
df=df.shift(axis=1)
df['Movie_ID']=df['User_ID'].str[0]
df['User_ID']=df['User_ID'].str[2:]
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Would be desired result.

Comment: That worked for the first row, but not the others. Here is the download for the data, for better understanding:  http://www.mediafire.com/file/1p545uwcawgqkay/combined_data_1.txt/file